ESP-8266 doesn't boot on particular power supply
I have an ESP-01 board (small board with ESP-8266) that usually works fine, but with one particular power supply, the LED just flashes rapidly and the module doesn't start. I know that these modules are susceptible to electromagnetic interference, so I measured the output of my power supply - it seems to give consistent 3.3V, but there are 12.5V AC from +/- to ground; I suspect that this is the problem.
Is this assumption correct?
If so, what would be the best option to solve this problem (using another power supply is not possible, since this is part of a bigger thing and I don't want to replace everything in there)? Add a coil or something somewhere? I'm usually a software dev and not an electrical engineer...
If this is not the cause of my problem, what else could possibly be wrong here?
EDIT: The power supply looks like the following (maybe I got the direction of a diode wrong or something):

Photos of the circuit:



Welcome! Is the module connected to anything else, USB or similar?

@winny no, its just connected to 3V3 and gnd

The 12.5 V AC could just be capacitive leakage. If you ground the minus output to proper ground, does it measure 0 V AC?

@winny if I do that my breaker trips :p

I hope that’s your RCB, it shouldn’t though. If you actually tripped your regular MCB, stop using the device immediately. Get yourself a different power supply and test again.

@winny like I said, this isn't a normal power supply but some internal transforming down + rectifying - these contacts were never meant to see the light of day, so them having some questionable voltages is ok I think; the built-in controller works perfectly fine with this as well... also "get a different power supply" won't solve this, because the problem is specifically with this one

Then we're going to need a schematic of your existing power supply.

@winny I drew the schematic and added it to my question

That's an non isolated capacitive dropper. Stop doing what you are doing immediately before you kill yourself. Connecting your MCU to it would put it and everything it touches at line potential, including you via your laptop.

@winny I may be inexperienced but I'm not dumb - I'm not touching any of this as long as its plugged in, and I'm also not connecting it to anything else

You probably need to troubleshoot it with another supply so that you can use an oscilloscope, or isolated probes. Your linear regulator lacks decoupling capacitors on input and output.

So how much volts is the relay coil? I can't see the marking on the relay. Capacitive supplies cannot provide much current, so if that's the supply you need to use and ESP consumes more than the supply provides, then there's really not much you can do, except for changing the supply to something that provides more current, or changing the ESP to something that consumes less current.
